# try catch validation for txt file

Tags: c#

I have a txt file named fileA.txt that I am trying to validate.

here is an example for fileA.txt

```
123, joshua, employee
134, vernon, manager
382, lisa, HR
```

So, what I am trying to do is read the contents of fileA and if e.g the value of the first index of the file is suppose to be the employee ID(an int) but has a string. I want to skip that line and go to the next using try catch. However, if everything is fine, I will return its value and add it to a new list. Any ideas on how may I do the validation part?

here is what I have for now to read the file and add it to a new list

```
public static List<Employee> readlist(string path)
{
    var employees = new List<Employee>();

    var content = File.ReadAllText(path);

    var lines = content.Split('\n');

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        var info = line.Split(',');

        employees.Add(new Employee
        (
            int.Parse(info[0]),
            info[1],
            info[2]
        ));
    }

    return employees;
}
```

Hope what I have provided is sufficient, thank you for all the help in advance!

Comment: Text file seems more like a csv file. So why not use a dedicated library to read a csv file? Eg. https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper

Comment: and you are looking for `int.TryParse` which returns a bool to indicate if the parsing was successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not need of using a try catch, you can simply use **Int32.TryParse** method to see if the expected value is a number, if is not a number then you just continue checking the other lines.

```
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var info = line.Split(',');

    var isIdValid = Int32.TryParse(info[0], out int employeeId);

    if(!isIdValid)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"'{info[0]}' could not be parsed as an Int32.");
        continue;
    }

    employees.Add(new Employee
    (
        employeeId,
        info[1],
        info[2]
    ));
}
```

Comment: thanks ! If I want to console.writeline an error message where do I code that at?

Comment: `Int32` you monster, use `int` like a normal human being. :D

Comment: @RandRandom damn i'm sorry its for a school project 